# Calling functions in a sequence to store results

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope

I have a global variable 'results' which is a string that will be used by two functions that run a process and append their output to the 'results' variable. 
However, the functions take time to process and return the result. Following is the current format of the code.

```
var results = 'Results: ';

router.get('/',function(req,res){

   app1.processImage(path, function(err, output){
   console.log('app1 processing completed');

   results = results+'app1 result:' + output;
  });

   app2.processImage(path, function(err, output){
   console.log('app2 processing completed');

   results = results+'app2 result:' + output;
  });

 console.log('Both processes are completed');

 console.log(results);// none of the results printed.

});
```

When I try to print the results, it doesn't have the outputs yet. 
the program produces output like this

**current output:**

```
Both the processes are completed

Results:

app2 processing completed

app1 processing completed
```

**Expected output:**

```
app1 process completed

app2 process completed

Both the processes are completed

Results: app1 result : true , app2 result:true
```

Notice that the current output results are empty as the functions are not processed yet. How can I get the results properly stored in the variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

This is a race condition.  You should look into using Promises.  With promises you will be able to let your script wait before executing the next item using `.then()` or `.done()`